# Dynamic prepared statements with sqlsrv (MSSQL) in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, dynamic, prepared-statement

### Generating the statement elements

I am trying to create an MSSQL prepared statement in a generic way.

Basically, I loop trough the fields, and add them to the prepared SQL string and to the reference parameter (scroll down to see the code).

This results in (names removed):

**Prepared query: :**

> INSERT INTO table
>   ([field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],[field],VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

and 
**sPrepStatement:**

```
return array(&$aLine[0],&$aLine[1],&$aLine[2],&$aLine[3],&$aLine[4],&$aLine[5],&$aLine[6],&$aLine[7],&$aLine[8],&$aLine[9],&$aLine[10],&$aLine[11],&$aLine[12],&$aLine[13],&$aLine[14]);
```

---

### Preparing the statement

I've tried the following 4 approaches to get this to work with the sqlsrv_prepare statement:

```
$oSQLStmnt = sqlsrv_prepare($dbhandle, $sPreppedSQL, eval($sPrepStatement));

$fReturnPrepVals = function(){ return eval($sPrepStatement); } ;
$oSQLStmnt = sqlsrv_prepare($dbhandle, $sPreppedSQL, $fReturnPrepVals);

$oSQLStmnt = sqlsrv_prepare($dbhandle, $sPreppedSQL,$aPrepValues);

$oSQLStmnt = call_user_func_array('sqlsrv_prepare',array($dbhandle,$sPreppedSQL, eval($sPrepStatement)));
```

This either does not work, or inserts blanks into the database.

This is the loop that executes the SQL:

```
foreach ($aLines as $iLineNum => $sLine) {
            $aLine = explode('|', $sLine);
            print_r($aPrepValues);
            print_r(eval($sPrepStatement));
            sqlsrv_execute($oSQLStmnt);
        }
```

The `eval($sPrepStatement)` works just fine, which makes sense. But I assume it is 'parsed too early' to work in the prepare statement. It should actually only be parsed as the query is executed, but I'm at a loss how to achieve that.

---

Code for the generation of sql statements:

```
<?php
//Setup the basic query
        $sSql = "INSERT INTO " . $sQName . "\n";
        $sFieldNames = "(";
        $sValues = "VALUES(";
        //This will be evalled to prepare the query, so inserting will be easy.
        $sPrepStatement = "return array(";
        //FieldIndex to keep track of the current column number
        $iFI = 0;
        $aLine = array();
        foreach ($aSQLQueries[$sQName]['fields'] as $sFieldName => $sQ) {
            $sFieldNames .= "[" . $sFieldName . "],";
            $sValues .= "?,";
            //Init the $aLine var to prevent errors
            $aLine[$iFI] = '';

            //This will be evalled, so no "" as that would parse it directly
            //The values wil be passed by reference
            $sPrepStatement .= '&$aLine[' . $iFI . '],';
            //Different approach
            $aPrepValues[] = &$aLine[$iFI];

            $iFI++;
        }
        $sFieldNames = substr($sFieldNames, 0, -1) . ")";
        $sValues = substr($sValues, 0, -1) . ")";
        $sPrepStatement = substr($sPrepStatement, 0, -1) . ");";
        $sPreppedSQL = $sSql . $sFieldNames . " " . $sValues;
```

Comment: Why does `$sPrepStatement` contain the keyword `return`? Also, why not use PDO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making it work with PDO, only to find that it could not handle millions of imports at a time, so I eventually used CSV import